# Does $\int f(ax)dx = \frac 1 a \int(fx)dx$? how to prove that?

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int f(ax)dx =  \frac 1 a \int(fx)dx$

If the above is right, how to show that? what are the rules in this case.

Is there a difference between indefinite and definite form of the above integral (for some boundaries a and b)?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the boundaries of your integral?

Comment: If the integral is indefinite, the variable x would have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have
$$
\int_{r}^{s}f(ax)\,dx
$$
Then, with the substitution
$$
x=\frac{t}{a},\qquad dx=\frac{1}{a}\,dt
$$
the integral becomes
$$
\int_{ar}^{as}f(t)\,\frac{1}{a}\,dt
=
\frac{1}{a}\int_{ar}^{as}f(x)\,dx
$$
The equality you write is untrue for indefinite integrals.

---

Let's assume you can write
$$
\int f(ax)\,dx=\frac{1}{a}\int f(x)\,dx
$$
where, for simplicity, I assume $f$ is defined and continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.

This is the same as requiring that, for all $x$,
$$
f(ax)=\frac{1}{a}f(x)
$$
by computing the derivative. Now try with $a=2$ and $f(x)=x^2$. On the left-hand side we have
$$
f(2x)=4x^2
$$
and on the right-hand side we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where I can learn more about this type of substitution. I'm only familiar with substitutions like u=ax. why it's untrue for indefinite integrals? and what is the solution in case of indefinite integral? Thanks.

Comment: @shudima Well, the substitution is $t=ax$: I just used $t$ instead of $u$.

Comment: Oh right. Can you just elaborate what happens for the indefinite integral?

Comment: One last question, if the boundaries are -infinity and plus infinity, then the first case apply and there are no changes to  boundaries, right?

Comment: @shudima You have to take care of $a>0$ or $a<0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a\int f(ax)\ dx=\int f(ax)\ d(ax)=\int f(y)\ dy$$